# Binding a template function from within a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, bind

In a continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478107/make-callback-accept-temporary-on-vs-2010). I'm trying to bind a given function that returns something-other-than void to be able to simply call f() later. However the following code fails to compile on GCC 4.4. It compiles on VS 2010, but the resulting program crashes.

```
template<typename RetType>
void _hideRet(std::function<RetType ()> func, RetType * ret)
{
    *ret = func();
}

template<typename FuncType, typename RetType, typename ParamType>
std::function<void ()> registerFunc(FuncType func, RetType * ret, ParamType param)
{
    auto f = std::bind(func, std::forward<ParamType>(param));
    return std::bind(_hideRet<RetType>, f, ret);
}

int myFunction(std::string text)
{
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    int ret = 0;
    auto f = registerFunc(myFunction, &ret, "text");
    f();
    std::cout << ret << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC produces this crazy message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/functional:70,
                 from func.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1_impl/functional: In member function ‘typename std::result_of<_Functor(typename std::result_of<std::_Mu<_Bound_args, std::is_bind_expression::value, (std::is_placeholder::value > 0)>(_Bound_args, std::tuple<_UElements ...>)>::type ...)>::type std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__call(const std::tuple<_UElements ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes ...>) [with _Args = , int ..._Indexes = 0, 1, _Functor = void (*)(std::function<int()>, int*), _Bound_args = std::_Bind<int (*(const char*))(std::string)>, int*]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1_impl/functional:1191:   instantiated from ‘typename std::result_of<_Functor(typename std::result_of<std::_Mu<_Bound_args, std::is_bind_expression::value, (std::is_placeholder::value > 0)>(_Bound_args, std::tuple<_UElements ...>)>::type ...)>::type std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args& ...) [with _Args = , _Functor = void (*)(std::function<int()>, int*), _Bound_args = std::_Bind<int (*(const char*))(std::string)>, int*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1_impl/functional:1668:   instantiated from ‘static void std::_Function_handler<void(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Bind<int (*(const char*))(std::string)>, int*))(std::function<int()>, int*)>, _ArgTypes = ]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1_impl/functional:2005:   instantiated from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<(! std::is_integral::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::__type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Bind<int (*(const char*))(std::string)>, int*))(std::function<int()>, int*)>, _Res = void, _ArgTypes = ]’
func.cpp:16:   instantiated from ‘std::function<void()> registerFunc(FuncType, RetType*, ParamType) [with FuncType = int (*)(std::string), RetType = int, ParamType = const char*]’
func.cpp:28:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1_impl/functional:1137: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::_M_clear_type*’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/tr1_impl/functional:1137: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(std::_M_clear_type*) [with _Res = int, _ArgTypes = ]’
```

I don't have enough knowledge of the inner STL workings to make anything out of that.

However while experimenting I found out that if I remove the second `std::bind` call from the registerFunc template like this:

```
template<typename FuncType, typename RetType, typename ParamType>
std::function<RetType ()> registerFunc(FuncType func, RetType *, ParamType param)
{
    return std::bind(func, std::forward<ParamType>(param));
}

// in main
auto tmp = registerFunc(myFunction, &ret, "text");
auto f = std::bind(_hideRet<int>, tmp, &ret);
f();
```

The code works as expected both in VS and GCC. So my conclusion is that the problem is in calling `std::bind(_hideRet<RetType>, ...)` from within a template function. The question is why is that a problem? And more importantly how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is absolutely amazing, but replacing :

```
auto f = std::bind(func, std::forward<ParamType>(param));
return std::bind(_hideRet<RetType>, f, ret);
```

by :

```
std::function<RetType ()> f = std::bind(func, std::forward<ParamType>(param));
return std::bind(_hideRet<RetType>, f, ret);
```

under Visual Studio 2010 runs as expected (which is essentially what you did by moving the second `bind` out of `registerFunc`). I'm trying to make sense out of it, but until then, that seems like a workaround for your issue,

Comment: @Fiktik: I wish I understood why :) Your original code should be working from my point of view

Comment: ParamType could be wrong and instantiated as `const char*`, while the correct ParamType would be `std::string`.

Comment: It could be even: `return std::bind(_hideRet<RetType>, std::function<RetType ()>(std::bind(func, std::forward<ParamType>(param))), ret);`

Comment: @smerlin ParamType of course instantiates as `const char *`, I'm counting on it and require it to work this way. This is also the reason why I use template type for FuncType instead of `std::function<RetType (ParamType)>` - because it would be unnecessarily restricting.